# checking whether a particular folder exists in user's mailbox of exchange online using ews soap request

Tags: exchangewebservices

> I am trying to fetch the folders in exchange online user's mailbox
>   using ews soap request and making to make a dictionary of path -> id
>   basis.

ex

```
inbox -> id1
inbox/1 -> id2
sentitems -> id3
```

using these id's, I am able to restore messages in users mailbox.

So is there any way I can directly check whether some folder exists in user's mailbox or not.

Current soap request that I am using now ->

```
        <soap:Body>
        <FindFolder Traversal="Shallow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
          <FolderShape>
            <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
            <t:AdditionalProperties>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:ParentFolderId"/>
            </t:AdditionalProperties>
          </FolderShape>
          <ParentFolderIds>
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="root"/>
          </ParentFolderIds>
        </FindFolder>
    </soap:Body>
```

Now it is giving me folder in root with parent id. then I am fetching again using folderId instead of t:DistinguishedFolderId.
So can I directly check whether a folder exists inside a particular parent or not, so I will only create the folder if it doesn't exist and if it does, I will use the returned folderId for createItem.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Existence in what definition?  Existence by folder name or by folder id?  And if by folder name, is it folder name in a particular path or folder name regardless of path?  It might just be better to call SyncFolderHeirarchy and then you have the full tree in one call and can do your checks locally.

Comment: @DavidSterling-MSFT yes checking locally is a good idea. So how I can get all the mail folders with parent folderId and path? path is must because making a dictonary of display name to FolderId will be a bad idea because display name (folder name) are not unique. I will make a dict like `Inbox/f1 -> f1_id,   Inbox -> Inbox_id,  SentItems/f1 -> f1_id`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link.  Basically you need to call syncFolderHierarchy and set the shape to include the props that you want returned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-synchronize-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: I am facing lot of problems making a dict of path -> id for mailbox.
Suppose I don't any sync state because I backed up my data using rest api and restoring using soap request. So in this case, I want to restore the message in the same folder where it belongs. For that I have path.